# What non-actor did the director Robert Bresson cast as the French king?

Tags: production, casting, the-trial-of-joan-of-arc

I read (in a *New Yorker* article, "Clio at the Multiplex," many years ago) that the French director Robert Bresson made a movie about Joan of Arc, cast with non-professional actors, called *The Trial of Joan of Arc* (orig.: *Procès de Jeanne d'Arc*). (I remember reading that he cast trial lawyers as the Inquisitors, because they knew how to ask probing questions.) I also read that he cast a non-actor to play the French king. What I wonder is, who did he choose to cast for the role? How was he appropriate for the role (like the lawyers for the Inquisitors)?